# Trying to support unicode in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, character-set

I am doing a project in which I have to save tweets into my MySQL database.  The problem is some tweets contains smilies and other symbols which I am not able to save - it shows error like below:

> Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x82. ...' for column 'text' at row 1

I was trying to convert to `utf8mb4` using [this link tutorial](http://Incorrect%20string%20value:%20'%5CxF0%5Cx9F%5Cx98%5Cx82.%20...'%20for%20column%20'text'%20at%20row%201), and in step 5, I have changed `my.ini` file in my **C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6** directory. But when I do

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

in my MySQL console, I am not getting the desired result, meaning my character set is not changed to `utf8mb4` - it is still `utf8`.

Please guide me how to resolve this, as I am new to this. I have attached an image to the step 5 (*Modify connection, client, and server character sets*) of the above tutorial.[image]

Comment: your link to tutorial is not working,please check

Answer (score 1):

You need `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8` to get  and a number of other emoji.

You need `SET NAMES utf8mb4` after connecting.

You also need to make sure `SHOW CREATE TABLE` says `utf8mb4`.

Your "this link tutorial" seems to be broken.  I would like to see what is says.  (And perhaps find an error in it.)

[More discussion of utf8mb4](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#4_byte_utf8).